# ¿Por que no funciona el return de mi función?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Programando en React estoy intentando que mi función devuelva el valor de mi localización actual pero me devuelve Undefined, en cambio, cuando el mismo valor lo imprimo en consola desde la función sí funciona. ¿Por que está devolviendo undefined?

```
export default class Distance{

getPos(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position)=>{
        console.log(position) ;
    })
}
getPos2(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos)=>pos)
}


console(){
    console.log(this.getPos2()) //Devuelve undefined
    this.getPos() //Devuelve el valor esperado
}

}
```

**Quité el código de la clase que era irrelevante**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al ser una función asíncrona, no puedes recuperar directamente el valor como lo estas intentando, puedes conseguirlo mediante un `Promise`, así:

```
export default class Distance {

    getPos() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            console.log(position);
        })
    }

    getPos2() {
        return new Promise((res) => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(res);
        });
    }

    console() {
        this.getPos2().then(res => console.log(res));
        this.getPos();
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, excelente respuesta, me srivió